# NestedScrollView not respecting childs height

Tags: android, height, overlay, android-nestedscrollview

I have a collapsing layout with tab layout and view pager.

Inside the viewpager, in the first tab, I have a NestedScrollView with a lot of children. The problem is: the NestedScrollView is not respecting the children height.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        .... Lots of children

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The last TextView of this LinearLayout doesn't show. If I put a margin bottom in the TextView of 50dp, it does show.

What I'm missing?

Full code: https://gist.github.com/guuilp/81f06c8a5581d2a9ce0a19dcf6c12ccc

Comment: Have you tried using wrap_content on you nestedscrollview instead of match_parent??

Comment: Yes, I've tried. Didn't work.